# Как установить libpng в MinGW?

Tags: mingw

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как установить `libpng` в `MinGW`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google для винды советует [так](http://tjaden.strangesoft.net/loadpng/mingw.html)

IMHO если у Вас просто есть хэдеры и библиотеки положите хэдеры в ...MinGW\include, а библиотеки в понравившееся оглавление из списка, выдаваемом

```
gcc -print-search-dirs
```

Comment: Можно поподробнее, мне надо откомпилировать http://pngnq.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @lorents, откровенно, я этот пакет не собирал. Посмотрел, IMHO - по Вашей ссылке заходите в SVN, там есть файл INSTALL. Читаете, делаете.

А что не получается ?

Comment: он требует установить libpng,  я не знаю как

Comment: @lorents, действовать по [этой инструкции](http://tjaden.strangesoft.net/loadpng/mingw.html) (For the extremely lazy) пробовали ?

Comment: Сделал, но все равно требует libpng версии новее 1.2

Comment: @lorents, вот мой запрос в гугле:

    MinGW libpng

вот [еще одна ссылка](http://wiki.openttd.org/Compiling_on_MinGW) с libpng-1.5.11. Вроде тут все расписано.

Наверное (насколько я вижу) можно сразу из нее перейти [сюда](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/) и скачать последнюю версию.

Comment: попытался установить libpng, потребовал установку zlib хотя он установлен уже. Решил сделать как написано в инструкции в ссылке., которую вы дали. Вроде все правильно сделал, и получил библиотеку zlib1.dll. libpng все равно требует zlib.

Вообще умываю я руки от pngnq. Большое спасибо что хотели помочь мне!